# Objective C - Get alignment of a CTParagraphStyleRef?

Tags: objective-c

I have a `CTParagraphStyleRef` how can I determine the alignment of this paragraph style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CTTextAlignment` its an enum defined as:

```
kCTLeftTextAlignment = 0,
kCTRightTextAlignment = 1,
kCTCenterTextAlignment = 2,
kCTJustifiedTextAlignment = 3,
kCTNaturalTextAlignment = 4
```

Here is the Apple [Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTParagraphStyleRef/Reference/reference.html)